# Google Maps API (GMS) map doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

Im trying to make the map automatically follow the user (location) but somehow the app either it crashes (no error message) or the map doesn't show up when I start up the app. What have I done wrong?

I have tried without the locationManager func, and then it does work. Are there any other ways to follow the user?

```
    class GMSTestViewController: BaseViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var manager:CLLocationManager!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //Setup Location Manager
            manager = CLLocationManager()
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()

            //Map type
            mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain
        }

        override func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let userLocation = locations.last
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                                                              longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 8)
            let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(.zero, camera: camera)
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            self.view = mapView

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = center
            marker.title = "Current Location"
            marker.snippet = "XXX"
            marker.map = mapView

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }
```

It looks like this when I start it up, and then it keeps blinking with the map (on the users location).
[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot/output of the crash?

Comment: @JohnFarkerson I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to do it is to use key-value observing (KVO):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options:0, context:nil)
}

deinit {
    mapView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"myLocation", context:0)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if(keyPath! == "myLocation"]) {
        let location = [object myLocation]

        let target =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);

        mapView.animateToLocation(target)
        mapView.animateToZoom(17)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for these things :-

- You have set the delegate of your `GMSMapview` *@IBOutlet* to self

  ```
         mapView.delegate = self
  ```
- You have updated your info.plist file with specific key's
- You have a proper internet connection.
- You have configured Google Maps in your `AppDelegate`

  ```
      var googleApiKey = String(_yourAPIkey)  
      GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleApiKey)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Google map]

It seems that google map is not appear in your view.I think you want to get view like in image.

So i suggest you to download **Google map SDK** version **below 1.10** because I am facing this problem too many times.

I suggest you to **download google map SDK 1.9.1** for google map from below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases

Just try to use **version 1.9.1**  once. Hope this thing works

NOTE: If you want to use Google map's place auto complete and other new services then use higher versions of Google map SDK

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Fixed by getting new API Key.
As I discovered, you need two keys: one for Google Places, one for Google Maps. At least for testing purpose.

In Google docs it doesn't mention.